# Can't find an option to lock my workstation

Tags: macos, password, login, login-screen

I'm trying to lock my workstation but when I look for one or Google for any other buttons/keyboard shortcuts, either none of them work or they are not present on my screen.

I don't see any options besides logoff, shutdown, restart, standby. Resuming from standby does not lock the workstation either.

I've been Googling for like half an hour now and nothing works.

**How can I lock my workstation without logging off completely?**

Answer (score 2):

In macOS High Sierra (10.13) there is a 'Lock Screen' option built in the Apple menu. And finally a shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> :-)

[image]

**Old solution for me:**

Or you can get a Keychain Lock in your menubar.

- Open Keychain Access
- Go to 'Preferences'
- Activate 'Show keychain status in menubar'
- There appears a lock in your menu bar.
- Click on it and choose 'Lock Screen'.

[image: Keychain Status in menubar]

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Prefs, and require a password to turn off screensaver.  Set the time period for requiring the password to "immediately".  Set a hot corner to trigger the screen saver.  Then, you would move the mouse to the hot corner to 'lock' the screen, requiring a password to unlock it.

Alternatively, under Users and Groups, turn on the setting to display the Fast User Switching menu in the menu bar.  From that menu there is an option to display the login window.  This will lock the machine, requiring a password to get back in.

Comment: I've tried the require password option but after the screensaver comes on it still never asks for a password. The fast user switching option is not there.

Comment: Fast user switching should be under login options

Comment: mike_dowler no, it isnt there im afraid

Comment: @ggg The answer & comment given by mike_dowler are correct. Just to be precise, go to Apple > System Preferences > Users & Groups. Click on the Login Options button at bottom left. Now to the right you will see a number of checkboxes, one of which is labelled *Show fast user switching menu as*. This needs to be ticked. If it's not, click on the padlock at bottom left and enter your password. Once it's unlocked you can tick the checkbox. Exit System Preferences. Now at top right of the menu bar you'll see your account name/icon. Click on this and select Login Window. Now you've locked your Mac.

Comment: @monomeeth I can't find 'login options'

Comment: Aah, let me guess, you're account isn't set up to administer the Mac. If you haven't got administrator privileges you won't see the Login Options. So, if it's your computer, you'll need to log in using an Admin account. If someone else has set up the accounts and you don't have a password for an Admin account, you'll need to ask them to set it up for you.